# why taking too long time to insert rows in a mysql table even after using multithreading when table has some relationship

Tags: mysql, multithreading, innodb, foreign-key-relationship, long-integer

I wanted to insert **200000** rows into a table through JDBC mysql connection.My table has three columns **DISTRICT1**(Id,Name,country).I used **multi-threads** to perform insert operation ,and it inserted data in less than 1 minutes.Then again I tried to perform similar operation on **DISTRICT2**(Id,Name,country) table ,in this case it is taking **very very long time** (more than 2hours) to insert rows (just like it does with single thread).The only difference between the tow tables is that **DISTRICT2** table has a  field **Id** which is linked to other tables through **foreign-key-relationship** while **DISTRICT1** table has no such relationship.**Also the other difference is of mysql engine ,DISTRICT1  has ENGINE=MyISAM while it is ENGINE=INNODB for DISTRICT2**
Also it gave `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when I used **PreparedStatement** instead of **Statement** .Does it has some relation with **connection pooling**?

Please tell **why does it take so long time** when table has some relationship?I used same program code to insert both the tables.I used following code to do so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  for (int i = 1; i <200001; i=i+10000) {
      Runnable worker = new MyRunnable4District(i);
          executor.execute(worker);
      }
  executor.shutdown();
 }
```

the class MyRunnable4District is shown below

```
public class MyRunnable4District implements Runnable {
 public int size;

 public MyRunnable4District(int n) {
  this.size = n;
 }

 public void run() {
  Connection con = null;
  try {

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/project",
     "root", "root");

   String[] countries = { "ARGENTINA", "US", "UK", "INDIA", "UKRAINE",
     "CHINA" };

   for (int id = size; id < size + 10001; id++) {
    int districtId = id;
    String districtName ="columbia"+id;
    String districtCountry = countries[id % 6];
    String query="INSERT INTO district "+"VALUES ("+districtId+",'"+districtName+"','"+districtCountry+"')";
    //PreparedStatement stmnt =con.prepareStatement(query);
    Statement stmnt =con.createStatement();
    stmnt.executeUpdate(query);
   }

  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   try {
    con.close();
    System.out.println("thread number with size "+size+" completed");
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't cleaning up your resources. You should [close](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) your statements after you finished using them.

It would however be a much better idea to use a PreparedStatement and reuse it with different parameters.

Also, you might want to consider using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: hi Mark,If closing Statements is the problem then why it executed fine with table district2 which has no foreign key relationship.In that case it inserted in less than 2min about 2million rows successfully.

Comment: @user575854: Are you running the client and server on different machines?

Comment: @mark , no I m running it on my local machine.I think th problem  is due to INNODB engine used in other table.please tell me the fix of this issue

Comment: @nikhil: *I m running it on my local machine* - I guessed that might be the case. The problem might be because your client is taking resources from your server and vice versa. When your server is hevaily loaded this can cause your badly written client to fail. Improving the client code and correctly closing unused resources will reduce the problem, but ideally you should run your client and server on different machines.

Comment: @mark :I tried it again with closing statments and resources ,still it takes too long  time to populate 2 million rows.The problem  gets resolved and similar table got populated in less than 1 min when the table is created with MYISAM engine instead of INNODB. I am using mysql 5.0

Answer (score 0):

You should try multi-value inserts. For example:

```
INSERT INTO district VALUES (id1,name1,country1),(id2,name2,country2),(id3,name3,country3);
```

This can provide a significant performance boost, especially if you need to do this when connecting to a remote server. In addition to reducing network roundtrips (or even out of process calls on a local machine), the server will have to process fewer queries. Also, if you leave auto commit enabled for InnoDB, you will now have one transaction per batch instead of one per statement.

The Connector/J JDBC driver will do this for you if you set the rewriteBatchedStatements option true. I think this feature was added in a 3.1.x driver release for simple INSERTs like yours. In later versions, rewriteBatchedStatements has been enhanced to support more complex statements. Search on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for rewriteBatchedStatements.

Or you can rewrite your code to manually construct multi-value insert statements. One thing to watch out for is the maximum packet size. You need to make sure the insert statement stays below that. So, either make [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) very large while importing the data or break up your batches as they get close to max_allowed_packet.